# SQLAlchemy exits with error "Did not recognize type 'LONG RAW' " when using automap_base with Oracle db

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I have created a simple table with sqlalchemy:

```
class SimpleTable(base):
     def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name

     __tablename__ = 'simple_table'

     id = Column(Integer, Sequence('id_seq'), primary_key=True)
     name = Column(String(40))
```

I submitted it to the oracle db using `base.metadata.create_all()` and I got a table with these fields:

```
ID    NUMBER(38,0)
NAME  VARCHAR2(40 CHAR)
```

So far so good. I put in some dummy data and tried to retrieve it but the following piece of code didn't work:

```
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

My_table = Base.classes.simple_table

data = session.query(My_table.name, My_table.id).all()
print(data)
```

I get this error:

```
SAWarning: Did not recognize type 'LONG RAW' of column 'objectdata'
  % (coltype, colname)
```